# Filter list of scheduled tasks by taskname

Tags: cmd, windows-task-scheduler

running the cmd command

```
schtasks /query /fo LIST
```

Gives me a list of all scheduled tasks running on my system. Example:

```
HostName:      CHESTNUT105B
TaskName:      Calculator
Next Run Time: 12:00:00, 10/28/2010
Status:        Running

HostName:      CHESTNUT105B
TaskName:      GoogleUpdateTaskMachineCore
Next Run Time: At logon time
Status:

HostName:      CHESTNUT105B
TaskName:      GoogleUpdateTaskMachineCore
Next Run Time: 13:02:00, 10/28/2010
Status:

HostName:      CHESTNUT105B
TaskName:      GoogleUpdateTaskMachineUA
Next Run Time: 17:02:00, 10/27/2010
Status:
```

How can I filter the list so it only shows me the details of the task 'Calculator' ?

the \tn argument gives me an error `Invalid Argument / Option`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `/` instead of `\`. This works just fine.

```
schtasks /query /fo LIST /tn Calculator
```

Comment: in windows 7x64 when i put the /tn switch always gives error... tryed several ways with/without quotes in the task name... no luck... one more 'shitty MS thang'...

Comment: ca you use wildcards in the /tn argument ?

Comment: this example from next answer clarifies the usage of backslash in tn. `schtasks /Query /TN \Microsoft\Windows\Backup\Microsoft-Windows-WindowsBackup`

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunatly I can not add a comment to ZEE's comment (not enough "reputation").

With the /TN switch you have to use the "path" - containing the folder in the task scheduler. Or you get an error:

> "ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified."

For example:

```
schtasks /Query /TN \Microsoft\Windows\Backup\Microsoft-Windows-WindowsBackup
```

(see also Jonathon Kellers Blog: http://www.jonathankeller.com/2012/02/schtasks-query-tn-tasks-over-network.html).

For better output I recommend the switch "/fo list" -> output as a list and verbose "/v":

```
schtasks /Query /TN \Microsoft\Windows\Backup\Microsoft-Windows-WindowsBackup /fo list /v
```

Answer (score 0):

```
schtasks /query /fo LIST | findstr "Calculator"
```